# Create c# lambda expression in a loop

Tags: c#, sharepoint, lambda

How can I convert the following lambda expression for running a SharePoint query in CSOM to accept an array of parameters:

Current working version:

```
var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(listItems,
    items => items.Include(
        item => item["Title"],
        item => item.RoleAssignments
    )
);
clientContext.Load(list, l => l.Id, l => l.DefaultDisplayFormUrl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How I would like it to work:

```
var fields = new List<string>()
{
    "Title",
    "ID",
    "DocumentOrder",
    "FileRef"
};

var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(listItems,
    items => items.Include(
        item => fields,
        item => item.RoleAssignments
    )
);
clientContext.Load(list, l => l.Id, l => l.DefaultDisplayFormUrl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This throws an error, is it possible to pass in a dynamic list?

Comment: What is the error that's thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Though not ideal, I have been able to achieve what I am attempting to do by calling Load several times in a loop:

```
var fieldNames = new List<string>()
{
    "Title",
    "ID",
    "DocumentOrder",
    "FileRef"
};

var listItems = list.GetItems(query);

foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
{
    clientContext.Load(listItems,
        items => items.Include(
            item => item[fieldName]
        )
    );
}

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```